# sorting lists of python 3.6.3 with custom def

Tags: python, list, sorting

I'm Trying to sort a list in python with my own def

this is my code :

```
def mysort(a):

    for i in range(len(a)):
        if (a[i]<a[(i+1)]):
            a[i],a[i+1] = a[i+1],a[i]
            i=0
    return a

a = [2,3,4]

print(mysort(a))
```

The First Error I faced was List Is Out Of Range 
and when I looked at the list in live programming mode I saw that only the first item was replaced with the second one and the third that was the biggest number in the list did not come first

my list in live programming mode before the error:

```
[3,4,2]
```

how can i fix this?

Comment: If you are trying bubble sort, you are doing it wrong!

Comment: you cant do in one loop.

Comment: `for i in range(len(a) - 1):` to solve the out of range error, and still is not gonna be sorted

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a few components to your sort:

1- you are sorting in reverse order.
2- you must limit your sort to `len(a)-1`
3- when the swap contition is not met, you must increment the index.
4- you are changing the index in a for loop... you must use a while loop here.

```
def mysort(a):
    idx = 0
    while idx < len(a)-1:
        if a[idx] < a[(idx+1)]:
            a[idx] ,a[idx+1] = a[idx+1], a[idx]
            idx = 0
        else:
            idx += 1
    return a

a = [2,3,4]

print(mysort(a))
```

#### tests:

```
a = [2,3,4]
print(mysort(a))

a = [0, 1, 4, 3, 6, 2]
print(mysort(a))

a = [6, 4, 2]
print(mysort(a))

a = [-1, -1, -1, 1]
print(mysort(a))
```

#### output:

```
[4, 3, 2]
[6, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
[6, 4, 2]
[1, -1, -1, -1]
```

IDK what sort it is, but it looks like a bubble sort where you start again and again at the very beginning of the list

Comment: thanks, man you are the best

quick question

in my for loop, i edited the condition to len(a)-1 and it worked but 
i didn't understand the logic behind it, could you explain a little bit more?

Comment: i'm sorry i think you did not see my comment

Comment: You are comparing `elt` at location `idx`, with `elt` at location `idx+1`; if you set `idx` to be the last location in the sequence, the element at `idx+1` does not exist, and overshoots the size of the sequence, and throws an `IndexError`.